# How to solve - Console error log can not write in Log4j2 configured file

Tags: java, spring-boot, jboss, log4j2

I tried to configure log with the log4j2-test.xml
I can write the info and error logs which I logged in the code log.info() and log. error().

But, I can not write the console error for runtime exception such as null point exception, number format exception, etc in the log file. I am using JBoss server. The console error are logged in the jboss server log but I need to log in test-1.log file.

Can anyone suggest a way to that?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration monitorInterval="60">
  <Appenders>
    <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout>
        <Pattern>test-1.log</Pattern>
      </PatternLayout>
    </Console>
    <RollingFile name="TestDailyAppender">
      <FileName>/Test/test-1.log</FileName>
      <PatternLayout>
        <Pattern>test-1.log</Pattern>
      </PatternLayout>
      <Policies>
        <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true"/>
      </Policies>
      <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="20"/>
    </RollingFile>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <logger name="com" level="info">
      <AppenderRef ref="TestDailyAppender"/>
    </logger>
    <logger name="com" level="info">
      <AppenderRef ref="TestDailyAppender"/>
    </logger>
    <Logger name="org" level="info">
      <AppenderRef ref="console"/>
    </Logger>
    <Root>
      <AppenderRef ref="TestDailyAppender"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: Do you have example console output? More than likely it's being wrapped by a logger created by the server.

Answer (score 0):

Is your application deployed as WAR file ? If so , is the test-1.log file is getting generated in the desired folder ?

If the file is not getting generated at the startup of server , please add [jboss-deployment-structure.xml](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Class+Loading+in+AS7?_sscc=t) file in your project to exclude the Log4j logs from getting written into jboss server log.

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
<deployment>
<exclusions>
<module name="org.slf4j" />
<module name="org.slf4j.impl" />
</exclusions>
</deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

This xml config will exclude slf4j logs and will create the test-1.log file . Hope this helps.Thanks